# Country flags icons

Tags: icons

Is there any standard in *nix systems for country flags?

Like, [icon theme specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of thing (icon standardization) is too high a level to be included in unix or posix specifications, which is a good thing, because no one wants to see various implementations and distributions involved in the kind of in-fighting associated with say, standardizing web browser operations, etc.

However, within some fairly large subsets of the *nix world, there are loose attempts to do so. The link you posted is from freedesktop.org -- you can read more [about them on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedesktop.org).  They have been successful in bringing about some positive changes, such as use of a `$HOME/.config` directory in place of top level dot files, and the use of icon directories.

I'm not sure how country flags would fit into that.  The icon spec doesn't actually dictate which icons are to be used for what, so if what you mean is having a directory in that specification specifically for flags, you first have to make the case that the desktop actually has much of a use for such.